# Facebook $user locale auth needed?

Tags: facebook, api, access-token

I don't know why I'm getting this error:
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

I know one normally should use access tokens for this,
but in the facebook api it clearly says:

> *no access_token for publicly available data: uid, name, first_name, middle_name, last_name, sex, locale*

So they say you don't need the access token for Locale and that's just what I need.
Please take your time to read my code:

```
// create the Facebook Graph SDK object
require_once('facebook.php');
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'=>'273312646075066', // replace with your value
    'secret'=>'7a34df58fad450648249634c81ec17c5' // replace with your value
        ));

echo "<body>";

    // Show the content for the person who liked the page
    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

    //setting the language variables
    $fr = 'fr';
    $nl = 'nl';

    //setting the right content according to the language
    if(stristr($user_profile['locale'],$nl))
    {
        $lang = "NL";
        $_SESSION['lang']=$lang;
        include "form.php";
    }
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I failed to mention that this should be without the auth process (the approve app). Client's wishes

Comment: Hi Joeri, I have the same problem. I want to get the current locale to display an error message to inform the user that he must be logged in Facebook. Did you figured out with that question? Gregoire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make basic calls to the graph like http://graph.facebook.com/zuck or http://graph.facebook.com/4 or http://graph.facebook.com/cocacola.

All of those work.  However, notice I'm not putting on any access token.

When you make the call using the PHP SDK, it appends on the current access token. Check out the webserver traffic itself and you can see it.

So here's the catch.  To know the user id (or username) of the user interacting with your site, you must authenticate them or just ask them for their user id (highly improbable that they'd know it).

Answer (score 0):

You should first go through [authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) process first in order to make graph api calls

Comment: Oh, that's right, I failed to mention that my client doesn't want the auth process cause he thinks it will scare people away. So is there any way possible without using the auth process?

Comment: Besides checking manually? I don't think there is. If i remember correctly, if your app isn't authenticated, it cannot make any graph api calls. But i am not 100% sure, so i would suggest checking documentation.

Comment: Ok, I found the answer. I've been searching for over 5 hours for this and all of a sudden I found this http://www.devquotes.com/2011/03/20/how-to-create-a-facebook-page-dynamically-translated/

Comment: Keep in mind that this method doesn't work in all cases:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my problem, one can access the free facebook var with the simple
use of a signed request.

```
$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
    $locale = $signed_request['user']['locale'];
```

The way I could get my user locale was found on this page:

http://www.devquotes.com/2011/03/20/how-to-create-a-facebook-page-dynamically-translated/